# ElasticSearch 5.5: search inner field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following doc(s) index into ElasticSearch 5.5. Now I want to search all the docs that contain persons with id=P123. How should I write the JSON search Query?

```
   {
      "my_id": "ABC123",
      "legacy_id": "",
      "alias": "",
      "persons": [
        {
          "id": "P123",
          "roles": [
            {
              "role": "",
              "status": "",
              "status_start_datetime": ""
            }
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "id": "P124",
          "roles": [
            {
              "role": "",
              "status": "",
              "status_start_datetime": ""
            }
          ]
        },     
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Could you please also copy and paste you index mapping here?

Answer (score 0):

Below query should find what you are expecting:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "term": { "persons.id.keyword": "P123" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```